# Adding Microsoft.Owin.Security reference to Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, owin

I am adding SSO verification to an existing C# desktop app and need to add a reference to Microsoft.Owin.Security but it doesn't appear on the reference list when I search for it.

I installed the package through the NuGet Package Manager Console but I still can't see it in the reference list.
[I added the 'using' statement at the beginning of the form and am stuck with the enclosed error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SXbL.png)

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. Not just a screenshot of the error. In fact, you should include the text of the error and code - screenshots are harder to adjust text size for easy reading, more difficult to index by search engines, harder to copy and manipulate the text into answers, waste of bandwidth, sometimes blocked by firewalls etc. Always include the text - screenshots should only be used as a supplement to your post, not as the primary means of conveying textual information.

Comment: Try to update package for get last references: NuGet\Update-Package

Answer (score 0):

**From VS2022** > **Tools** > **NuGet Package Manager** > **Package Manager Console** >

To install
typo:

**NuGet\Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security -Version 4.2.2**

To uninstall
typo:

**NuGet\UnInstall-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security -Version 4.2.2**

[image]

Look at [nuget.orgp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security) as reference

Comment: I installed it through the package manager console but it still won't show up on the list when I try to add it as a reference

Comment: @roy_meir, What is the target .NET framework version of your project? Look under the Project > Properties > Target Framework.

Comment: Look at your project > Dependencies > Packages > Microsoft.Owin.Security > Message warning "Package 'Microsoft.Owin.Security 4.2.2' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework 'net7.0-windows10.0.22621'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project."

Comment: @roy_meir, set your Target framework to 4.8 in Project > Properties > Target Framework.